# parse error caused by include of a good file

Tags: c, parsing, compiler-errors, include

I'm debugging a very large project and I added in one file: `"file_1.c"` an include statement for another file `#include "header_2.h"`. I got 2 compilation errors:

> error (dcc:1633): parse error  near '100'   (Built from Project 'project_3')
>
> error (dcc:1100): member is incomplete   (Built from Project 'project_3')

but the locations of the errors didn't make sense, because the code there was part of a typedef:

```
typedef struct 
{
 unsigned char    A:1,       // <- first error here  (dcc:1633)
                  B:1,        
                  C:6;          
}TYPE_A;

typedef struct
{
 TYPE_A         D;        // <- second error here  (dcc:1100)   
 TYPE_B         E; 
 TYPE_C         F;         
}FOO_T;
```

Now, this header `header_2.h` is included in other c files and gave me no problems.

I thought that the case here could be circular include but I checked the header and there are include guards there. Once I remove the include, the parse errors disappeared and the compilation run OK (since the include was planted there for some code piece I removed).

I also checked the actual include line (in file_1.c) to see if maybe there was a parse error there, but nope.

What can cause this problem and how should I handle it?

**Note: the header itself is error free. It is included in other c files and shows no errors there. Also, without this specific include, the compiler runs fine.**

Comment: The type-specifier for the declarator must be `unsigned int`, `signed int`, or `int`,

Comment: I don't understand. Are you saying the types here are wrong?

Comment: try `unsigned   A:1, B:1, C:6;` (`unsigned char` GCC extension)

Comment: but I use unsigned char all over the project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the header which causes the problem contains something like

```
#define A 100
```

which changes the meaning of the token `A`.

That will only cause issues if the macro defined in the header is inadvertently used in another file; by themselves, the header and the other file are unproblematic.

Comment: 1) if this is true then my 2nd error is just a by-product of the 1st?        2) I checked the files for "100" and didn't see any hits :( but I guess the token can be hiding in some other file included

Comment: @noob: also, you can get a list of `#define`d symbols with gcc, or you can just grep all your headers; the former is more accurate, but the latter tells you where the defines are.